# Create script for test server

Tags: shell, unix, zsh

`#!/usr/bin/env zsh
./client localhost 5000 Bryan (my command)`

I would like to check if the parameter of my command is correct, in script zsh that means:

```
if 
first argument = int
second argument = int
third argument = string
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, all of those conditions must be true for the script to continue, yes?  Also, note that "string" means pretty much any character (A-Z, 0-9, punctuation) -- anything other than control characters.  Assuming that is the case, how about something like this:

```
  re='^[0-9]+$'
  echo " "
  echo "Parm 1: $1"
  if ! [[ "$1" =~ $re ]]; then
     echo "The first parameter must be an integer."
     exit 1
  fi

  echo " "
  echo "Parm 2: $2"
  if ! [[ $2 =~ $re ]]; then
     echo "The second parameter must be an integer."
     exit 2
  fi

  re='^[[:graph:]]+$'
  echo " "
  echo "Parm 3: $3"
  if ! [[ $3 =~ $re ]]; then
     echo "The third parameter must be an string."
     exit 3
  fi
  echo " "
  echo "Congratulations -- your parms are valid\!"
  echo " "
```

Edit: Here are some sample runs:

```
~/test1$
~/test1$./tmp 123 456 abdc

Parm 1: 123

Parm 2: 456

Parm 3: abdc

Congratulations -- your parms are valid\!

~/test1$./tmp abc 123 456

Parm 1: abc
The first parameter must be an integer.
~/test1$./tmp 12b 123 abc

Parm 1: 12b
The first parameter must be an integer.
~/test1$./tmp 123 4h5 abc

Parm 1: 123

Parm 2: 4h5
The second parameter must be an integer.
~/test1$./tmp 123 jkl asdf

Parm 1: 123

Parm 2: jkl
The second parameter must be an integer.
~/test1$
~/test1$
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note, if my assumptions are wrong, let me know and I can update the answer.

Comment: Ugh.  I just noticed you specifically asked for zsh -- which I am not familiar with.  There may be syntactical differences, but the logic remains the same.